# svn checkout/update without deleting existing (versioned) files on the disk

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-checkout

I'm executing a number of python scripts, all using parts of the same (big) framework. I use various versions of this framework, all under version control and since each test uses different parts of it, I decided it will be faster to checkout only the parts I need to. In other words, I was expecting to use sparse checkouts. My intention is step by step checkout an empty working copy, and update by update to have the (almost) complete framework collected over time. I'm using a python script with modulefinder to decide which parts of the framework I need for each project. So I get following:

Project Foo, Framework tree:

```
\R100
   \Framework
     \Module_1
       \Submodule_1
       \Submodule_5
     \Module_2
     \Module_3
```

Checkout routine:

```
svn checkout repo.url/Framework@100 local\R100\Framework --depth empty
svn update \local\R100\Framework --depth immediates --revision 100
svn update \local\R100\Framework\Module_1 --depth immediates --revision 100
svn update \local\R100\Framework\Module_1\Submodule_1 --depth immediates --revision 100
svn update \local\R100\Framework\Module_1\Submodule_5 --depth immediates --revision 100
svn update \local\R100\Framework\Module_2 --depth immediates --revision 100
svn update \local\R100\Framework\Module_3 --depth immediates --revision 100
```

Project Bar:

```
\R100
   \Framework
     \Module_1
       \Submodule_1
       \Submodule_2
     \Module_2
     \Module_3
```

Checkout routine:

```
svn checkout repo.url/Framework@100 local\R100\Framework --depth empty
svn update \local\R100\Framework --depth immediates --revision 100
svn update \local\R100\Framework\Module_1 --depth immediates --revision 100
svn update \local\R100\Framework\Module_1\Submodule_1 --depth immediates --revision 100
svn update \local\R100\Framework\Module_1\Submodule_2 --depth immediates --revision 100
svn update \local\R100\Framework\Module_2 --depth immediates --revision 100
svn update \local\R100\Framework\Module_3 --depth immediates --revision 100
```

Project Moo:

```
\R100
   \Framework
     \Module_1
       \Submodule_1
       \Submodule_3
     \Module_6
     \Module_9
```

Checkout routine:

```
svn checkout repo.url/Framework@100 local\R100\Framework --depth empty
svn update \local\R100\Framework --depth immediates --revision 100
svn update \local\R100\Framework\Module_1 --depth immediates --revision 100
svn update \local\R100\Framework\Module_1\Submodule_1 --depth immediates --revision 100
svn update \local\R100\Framework\Module_1\Submodule_3 --depth immediates --revision 100
svn update \local\R100\Framework\Module_6 --depth immediates --revision 100
svn update \local\R100\Framework\Module_9 --depth immediates --revision 100
```

The problem is, each consecutive update starts with deleting of the already existing files instead of checking out only the new to this working copy files. Is there any way to overcome that? I realize setting update/checkout depth is the reason but I want to overcome this telling the svn client "Fine, those files and folders are no longer in the scope of the checkout, but since they are already here, keep them anyway"

Answer (score 0):

The approach you decided to follow won't work well and I expect a lot of pain witch such a working copy. SVN provides tool that were designed with such cases in mind.

It seems to me that you are missing [vendor branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html) or [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html) in particular. You could research and implement one of these features or both in your SVN repository:

- Use [vendor branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html) to maintain customized codebase dependent on external code.
- Use [`svn:externals`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html) with tags in SVN to construct a working copy out of multiple projects or checkouts.